# How do I effect the page that a menu item redirects to?

Tags: routes, blocks

I am trying to do something that seems simple, but I have yet to have to do it with my development because I have always dealt with forms and views.

On the page that I get redirected to when I click on a menu item, I want to have a page with a href on it.

So for example, I have created a menu item as follows:

```
$items['admin/vendor/auth-stripe'] = array(
        'title' => 'Authenticate Stripe Account',
        'description' => 'In order to receive payments, you must authenticate your Stripe Account.',
        //'page callback' => '_bh_vendor_auth_stripe',
        'access arguments' => array('vendor administration'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

When I click on this menu item, I am taken to a page.  I want to add items to this page.  Namely an href link.

Do I need to create a block that only shows up on this page?  If so, how do I add a link on the page.  I know how to create a block programmatically using `hook_block_info`, but I am not exactly clear on putting content in this block programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_menu` serves, among other things, to map paths onto callback functions.  Whatever function is marked as the `page callback` for that path will be responsible for returning a either a rendered string of HTML or a Drupal render array.  So, for your very simple use-case, you could do the following (assuming your module's name is bh_vendor):

```
function bh_vendor_menu() {
 $items['admin/vendor/auth-stripe'] = array(
        'title' => 'Authenticate Stripe Account',
        'description' => 'In order to receive payments, you must authenticate your Stripe Account.',
        'page callback' => '_bh_vendor_auth_stripe',
        'access arguments' => array('vendor administration'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
 );
 return $items;
}

function _bh_vendor_auth_stripe() {
 return l('My link', 'my/path');
}
```

You could, in fact, define a block using `hook_block_info()` and `hook_block_view()`, then embed that block on your page by calling `module_invoke('bh_vendor', 'block_view', 'yourblockdeltahere')` but that really only makes sense if the stuff you're embedding is re-used elsewhere.  If it's only meant for this one page then you should stick the code to generate that markup in your `page callback` directly.

Another option, if this isn't for a module that's to be widely distributed and is only configuration for a specific site: use the Panels module.  You can create a panels page at a specific url (admin/vendor/auth-stripe) and embed whatever blocks/content you wish.  If you want it in code it is exportable and/or can integrate with Features.